# How to sync specific files (not folders) on Windows 7

Tags: windows, script, sync

I need to copy frequently 2-3 files from my current program build to several other folders. 
How can I do this? Most free autosync solutions like SyncToy work only on folders, not files.
Using .bat files doesn't look too comfy ^) Maybe there is a good freeware solution or script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested this, but I cannot see why you could not make a folder which you add to sync with SyncToy, Dropbox, Windows Live Mesh, etc, and then make symbolic links to the individual files you want to sync, within it.

eg.

```
cd synced_folder
mklink syncedfile.txt c:\%userprofile%\documents\syncedfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [FreeFileSync](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freefilesync/) (Free and Open Source). Though it is not meant to sync specifically only files, I usually set `include/exclude` filters to selectively copy only what files I want. You can either specify a pattern or paste filenames in the `include` list. There is a big funnel-shaped red button at the top-center of the window to set those filters